# Clustering based on comparison of two columns

Tags: python, sqlite, cluster-analysis

I have a data with below structure:

```
Row  UPC   Ref   Supplier
1    A1    B1    C1
2    A2    B2    C2
3    A3    B3    C3
4    A4    B5    C4
5    A5    B1    C5
6    A3    B2    C6
7    A1    B5    C7
8    A5    B3    C8
```

Now, I want to assign group number to each row if there is match of "Ref" column or "UPC" column in any of the rows. For example: If I start with row 1, I will look for "A1" in first column of rows 2 to 8. The matches is row 7. Now the Ref column for the row 1 and 7 matches row 4 and 5 so they will also be part of same group. Hence the first group will be row 1,4,5 and 7. Similarly for remaining items.

The output will be:

```
Row   UPC   Ref   Sup   Group
1     A1    B1    C1    1
4     A4    B5    C4    1
5     A5    B1    C5    1
7     A1    B5    C7    1
2     A2    B2    C2    2
6     A3    B2    C6    2
3     A3    B3    C3    3
8     A5    B3    C8    3
```

Please note that I am using Python for coding and using sqlite for storing the data.

I would really appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Inside SQLite, maybe create a self-join on UPC, call this view e.g. 'myview', and then create another join of myview with the original table, but on the Ref column.

Answer (score 0):

This is not clustering, but *connected components*.

If two records have the same value in either column, they are connected, and you want to find all connected components. There isn't really a need to do anything special here, just try to implement it.

If you want to save some effort, use `GROUP BY ColumnA` to have the database perform half of the work.